# Laptop hangs on startup but works fine on Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, start-screen, samsung-laptop

I have a Samsung RV511 Windows 7 home premium based laptop,it is 32 bit with 4 Gb Ram.
It worked fine until 6 months back when the screen started flickering when not on charging, after some days it wont boot on every press of the power key..I took it to a technician and he formatted it and fixed for a few days after which the problems started again, this time it would hang and freeze in the middle, and this was frequent if it was on battery.
So i plugged the charger always while working.
Now it worsened, It hangs when windows is loading during the welcome screen and upon restarting if i am super lucky then it wont happen again.
The interesting thing is it never hangs/freezes if i opt for the safe mode.
Also even if it starts-up successfully(in normal mode), i put it in sleep and wake it up later..the graphics driver fails to load the screen(it is fixed automatically sometimes after flickers n blinks with failure notification)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue. You could try rolling back the Graphics driver to something earlier, or see if there is an older version on the Samsung download page for your laptop.

Comment: Its really erratic, I did what you mentioned and now another problem started, the wifi adapter will stop automatically and then it would freeze, after it the blue screen appears and again freezes there unless I press the power button to shut it down.
I feel it m8 be multiple hardware issue